# Read last sheet of spreadsheet using pandas dataframe

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I ma trying to use pandas dataframes to read the last sheet of a spreadsheet since I don't need the rest. how do I tell python just to take the last one? I can not find a flag on the documentation that says how to do this. I can specify the sheet with sheet_name flag but this does not work for me since I don't know how many sheets I have

```
 raw_excel = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=0)
```

Comment: `sheet_name=-1`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.

Comment: @Neither, kindly post this as an answer, so that the question can be closed, and OP selects it as the answer

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks, someone already posted something like that I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ExcelFile function.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)

# See all sheet names 
sheet_names = xl.sheet_names  

# Last sheet name
last_sheet = sheet_names[-1]

# Read a last sheet to DataFrame
xl.parse(last_sheet)
```